# Button pressing sound's volume isn't consistent

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make a short arcade-like beep sound whenever the user clicks a movement button for a game. for this, I tried to use the code I always use to make audio:
in the MainActivity class I declared

```java
MediaPlayer bpress;
```

in the OnCreate function

```java
bpress = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.blop);
```

and in the OnClick

```java
if (view == left) {
   bpress.start();
}
```

and it does work, but the volume of the sound isn't consistent - it often plays on half the volume or becomes barely audible.

I tried switching to a different, longer audio file to see if the problem comes from the short length of the beep sound, but the problem remains.

Therefore, I'm almost certain that the problem is related to the fact that said buttons are pressed quickly, and many times. but I don't know why it happens or how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions to the problem.
Put this chunk of code inside your onClick listener

**Solution 1:**

```
mpBlob.stop();
   try {
     mpBlob.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
mpBlob.start();
```

**Solution 2:**

```
if(mpBlob.isPlaying()) {
    mpBlob.stop();
    mpBlob.release();
    mpBlob = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.blob);
}
mpBlob.start();
```

Comment: still inconsistent

Comment: also, the problem also occurs when the presses are far apart

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer, try it... it works fine for me

Comment: nope, still inconsistent

Comment: That's weird... for me that code works fine... maybe there is a problem in your audio file, or maybe I didn't understood your question :(

Comment: I tried to listen more carefully and now I believe the sound actually gets cut off rather than playing with a lower volume. still, I have no Idea what causes this

Comment: @Aviv I added a second solution try it out maybe it will be more consistent...

Comment: I tried running the code again today (without implementing your solution) and the sound no longer cuts off. I changed various things unrelated to the audio and I don't know which change (if any) fixed the issue. perhaps it is related to my phone performance being better coming right off the charger. But for now, I don't know how to replicate the issue to check your suggestion. either way, I doubt lt would work as the problem happens even when the sounds are far between, so I can't see how stopping the supposedly-not-playing audio can help